# React element rerender by key property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, render, rerender

I have to use key property for react element to be able to rerender it correctly.

```
<Element key={value} />
```

The problem is that I want it to rerender depending on multiple values like:

```
<Element key={value || value2} />
```

But I see it is not even checking `value2` so when it changes it is not rerendering.
How can I do that? Is there any other way?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you can say
```<Element key={`${value}-${value2}`} />```

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why you should need a variable `key` prop for your element; is it possible this is a case of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? Maybe it would be beneficial if you share more details about what you are trying to do as well as the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help guys. Changing it to a string with both values works.

```
<Element key={`${value}-${value2}`} />
```